# Cargo Fails to Compile hyper with Darwin Target

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, hyper

I have a CLI that I wrote and am trying to have it built for these targets in a Docker image based from the `rust:1.53-slim` image:

- `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`
- `x86_64-apple-darwin`
- `x86_64-pc-windows-gnu`

The Linux and Windows targets are building properly, but when I try to do the cross compile for the Darwin target, the `hyper` crate continues to fail to compile because of the following error:

```
$ cargo build --locked --release --target x86_64-apple-darwin

# ...
# OMITTED COMPILE OUTPUTS
# ...

= note: cc: error: x86_64: No such file or directory
          cc: error: unrecognized command line option '-arch'; did you mean '-march='?
          

error: aborting due to previous error

error: could not compile `hyper`
```

I've scoured the internet looking for clues or solutions to this but can't find anything thats helpful. Has anyone experienced or solved this before? Any guidance would be great!

---

EDIT:

Is there a GCC linker that I need to have installed via `apt-get` for it to properly compile for darwin?

Answer (score 0):

Cross-compiling still requires a native linker which supports the requested target (which in turns needs the system libraries).

You may have some luck with [osxcross](https://github.com/tpoechtrager/osxcross) or [crossbuild](https://github.com/multiarch/crossbuild) and overriding the linker (andc compiler) using a target-specific section in [.cargo/config.toml](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html) such as:

```
[target.x86_64-apple-darwin]
linker = "linker-path-here"
```

And/or setting the `CC` env var to the right cross-compiler.

Comment: Is there something i need to have installed via `apt-get` on the docker image for the darwin linker to be available or is it installed when the rustup target is added?